# How can I protect books in my study from rats/mice?

Tags: pest-control

I've discovered that rats/mice are living in my home. At night they come into my study and chew any books they can find, so I had planned to exterminate them by 
placing rat poison in the study. However, I'm worried that they could eat it and die in my study somewhere that I can't find them. What are the steps to take or alternative extermination methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/theres-a-mouse-in-my-house

Comment: @Doresoom : I'd say that they're related, but there might be other protection methods that aren't about extermination.

Comment: @Joe: Good point, maybe I was too hasty with the close hammer.

Comment: @Doresoom @Joe - Still sounds like a mouse problem, and is a duplicate of "theres a mouse in my house".  If this is just a question on protecting books, it should be reworded to be more general "What type of shelving/storage is best for books".  Even then it might not fit in with "Home Improvement".  The best solution here is to get rid of the mice, so I would say it's a duplicate question.

Comment: @Tester: I would like to argue to you, regarding saying this aduplicate question, because i m looking for some cheapest kind of mechanism which help my books to protect from rats,rather than giving priority to kill rats, my priority is to protect my books from rats,that's it

Comment: It'll probably be cheaper to set a few traps. They don't cost much (especially in comparison to a bookshelf), stay pretty much where you put them, and solve the rodent problem. Even if you're completely against killing them, there are humane live-traps available, still cheaper than a bookshelf. Unless you like having mice/rats in your house, I'd say getting rid of them is the best course of action.

Comment: Sankar - I know that you just want to protect the books, but the best way to do that (and probably most cost effective way) is to eliminate the pest problem.  So in essence this is a duplicate of "Theres a mouse in my house", which contains many ways to eliminate mouse/rat problems.

Comment: @Tester101 : even if there weren't non-extermination options, it's not an exact duplicate, because this one specifically called for not leaving bodies in random places; that means poison and cats are generally out.

Comment: @Joe: hmm, Agian Upvoted, because you are explaning , what i had thought in my mind, thanks

Comment: @Joe -  Most of the answers to the other question involve methods that would not leave bodies, and some even suggest ways to remove the pests without killing them.  I think this question is close enough (although possibly not an exact duplicate), to not add value by asking the question again in different words.  The root of the question is still about pest control, and most of the answers to the previous question also apply here.

Answer (score 4):

From a book protection, and not extermination standpoint, you could always build shelving that had doors on it -- like the ones used in law libraries, where a door drops down from the top to close things up.

(typically, they're glass or other clear doors, so you can see what's in there easily.)

Comment: Up-voted, Because aveSome Idea, but i m staying in a Rent Home, I need the Book Protection methods rather than Killing the rats

Comment: A glass-doored freestanding bookshelf would be a good option if you can't attach shelving to the walls in a rental property.

Comment: @Doresoom: i m living in a Rent House, that's not my own house, also the owner will not give any money for effort , so i m looking for some cheapest kind of mechanism which help my books to protect from rats, even-though i had shifted to some other rent home, there also i can reuse this mechanism.

Comment: Depending on the determination of the mice, a shelf built from wood would only slow them down.  The shelves should be built from something mice cannot chew through, and also be almost completely sealed (as mice can slip through the tiniest cracks).

Comment: I had a situation where mice had chewed into a cabinet and then out through the back and had then chewed out the plaster to make a void and were living there between the back of the cabinet and the wall.

Answer (score 2):

I would think the mice/rats are not chewing on the books as a source of food (unless they really want lots of fiber in their diets), rather they are most likely gathering nesting material.  As such, you may be able to prevent them from chewing your books by providing them another source of nesting material.

Try placing a few rolls of toilet tissue on the book shelf, and see if the rodents prefer that over the books.  If that doesn't work you might also try some other materials, like cardboard, or other paper products like spare printer paper.

Ultimately the solution here is to eliminate the pest problem, there are some good suggestions on how to do that in this question "[Theres a mouse in my house"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/theres-a-mouse-in-my-house).

Comment: I have kept pet fancy rats for some time, and from my observations they sometimes also chew things to see if there is anything inside them worth eating. It seems to me that they simply do not realise that books are paper all the way through until they have chewed a few.