# How can I figure out where squirrels are entering my attic?

Tags: pest-control, pest

Squirrels keep getting in my attic but I can't figure out where they're coming in. There may also be chipmunks, as I found a bunch of sunflower seed shells inside a lawn chair bag that was laying up in the attic. I can't figure out how they are getting in the attic. There is a vent above the kitchen that I was suspecting but when I checked it the flaps were closed.

How do I locate the entrance where the chipmunks/squirrels are getting into my attic?

Comment: Question is very vague - not really answerable, as none of us have any way of knowing (without more details from you) exactly what problems may exist with your house.

Comment: What's the question? How do I find the entry point? Or is it How do I deter squirrels from entering my attic? Or maybe How do I catch squirrels that are currently in my attic? Please be more descriptive of your goal here.

Comment: related : http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/how-are-the-rats-getting-in

Comment: I'm seconding Doresoom's comment. Can you please edit your question to make it clear what problem you need help with, otherwise it will get closed.

Answer (score 6):

There may be many points, and they may not be what you think. First off, squirrels can squish themselves down and fit through a hole much smaller than you'd think they could. Don't rule any holes out because they're too small (well, other than say the vents in your soffit).

Check soffits, vents, corners, anywhere wiring or pipes enter (anywhere in the house).

It's possible they're coming in around the foundation, or through your garage, and then climbing up walls or even on the inside of walls. Look for any holes, including under decks, stairs, etc.

In the winter, seeing their tracks in the snow can point you in the right direction (but the sooner you can get rid of them the better so don't wait until winter).

Answer (score 3):

Start from the other end.  Find where you know they've been, and look around for signs of a trail.  Damaged or displaced materials like insulation, footprints in dust, chewed areas, droppings, etc., and see if you can follow it down.  If you know they are up there pretty often, try spreading something like talcum powder all around, they might leave a trail in it or even track it along their way out.  The way they get out is probably the same way they get in. If the tracks go a little way then fade, spread more in that area.  Keep repeating, find part of a path they take and cover that to find more of the path.

Just an idea, I have no experience trying it to know if it will work.

Comment: If you're really lucky, you'll find little talcum powder footprints outside, leading down the drainpipe from a soffit or something.

Answer (score 1):

I must agree that the question is largely unanswerable. However, your problem now is no longer "where" are they entering. Squirrels are very determined little critters. So, now that they have decided your home is theirs, your greater concern is changing their minds. There are three options:

1. Find where you think the most likely entry point is and set up a trap and relocate the animals (ALL of them),
2. Find every possible point of entry and cover with hardware cloth/metal flashing, or
3. Terminate.

Option three is an unpopular choice for some people and you may be one offended by the suggestion. If so, my apologies, but this is my experienced "opinion".

Comment: If you trap them, you should take them a far distance away. They are pretty good at finding their way back. Termination should really be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Try motion activated camera(s).